# Android custom listview with space between items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

How can I make a listview as follows:

[image: listview with spaces between each item]

and one more question about row layout, i have such layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/deals_list_row_gradient_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dealImg"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:src="@drawable/test" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dealDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet dolor sed a ite amkt Lantin dolor latim dk kuitshen sed iditur anet" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/smth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:text="...................................................."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dealNewPrice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text="1248$"
                    android:textColor="@color/deals_list_new_price"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dealOldPrice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dealNewPrice"
                    android:text="2500$"
                    android:textColor="@color/deals_list_old_price"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but i have trouble with imageview, i dont understand how will be correctly to set its width and height
also lot of people say me that using RalativeLayout is bad idea

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with the modified list view layout.  Here's How I implemented:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the resulting view:

[image: corrected list view]

#### One thing to note:

This screenshot was taken on an xhdpi device -- you can see an issue with your dashed lines.  Consider using a [ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) instead and specify `android:dashGap` and `android:dashWidth`.

Comment: one more question how can i set image height = layout height, i mean how to remove white space in bottom and top of image

Comment: @iCaesar please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: This solution cause gap between left edge of screen and scroll of ListView

Answer (score 7):

use these two lines in your listview in the xml:

```
 android:divider="@android:color/transparent" 
 android:dividerHeight="10px"
```

and for your Imageview try these two additions:

```
 <ImageView
            ...
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 />
```

Comment: Thx, it works for ListView.
image view still not working correctly

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for cards style UI as found in Google Now etc. You can use the custom library Cards-UI to get a similar effect. https://github.com/afollestad/Cards-UI

Comment: i want that image height = layout height (with textview) such as on image

Comment: Please add more information to this answer. Link only answers may break in future

Answer (score 0):

Set these two properties in your ListView, it will provide top and bottom margin

```
   android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
   android:dividerHeight="10dp"
```

and set

```
   android:layout_margin="7dp"
```

to your ListView to get the left and right margins, it will give the desired layout

Comment: Please avoid caps lock